# Are the dtproj projects dead?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

We are at the end of 2022, but still I am not able to open my SSIS projects (dtproj) in Visual Studio 2022. Is SSIS projects at the end of their life?

I have already installed [Microsoft Analysis Services Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects2022) but no luck!

Comment: No but I would definitely not do any new work using SSIS

Comment: Why not? What can I use instead?

Comment: In my last non-cloud project we used powershell to bulk transfer data and stored procedures to process it. If you are on cloud, there's not really any reason to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is SSIS projects at the end of their life?

No they are not. As
https://andyleonard.blog/2022/08/updated-ssis-extension-v4-1-2-includes-support-for-visual-studio-2022/
Microsoft SSIS Team are targeting preview of VS2022 Integration Services Extension for the end of CY22. So you should wait till then!